# Combined field login form Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, forms, swift

I love a beautiful interface and I think Facebook and Twitter have hit it on the head when it comes to a beautiful UX/UI. I am looking to create a form that looks like it is combined rather than separate fields spaced apart from each other. Here is the link to the form I am trying to create, I would post the picture but I don't have enough reputation.

http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/apgetwikiimage?21304,2

I tried smashing the fields together and editing the cornerRadius for them so it would look like that but that did not work, I also tried a table view which did not work as well. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SOF. Your question is too general. You need to demonstrate what you tried to achieve this and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed both `UITextFields` in a `UIView`. Set the `UITextFields'` `borderStyle` to `None`. Space the `UITextFields` an appropriate distance from each other and from the edges of the `UIView` they're embedded in. To get the line in the middle, line is shown in your link, make a `UIView` between your two `UITextFields`. Set the `backgroundColor` to whatever you want the line to be an set the `height` to 1. Finally, on the `UIView` that contains all of this, set `layer.cornerRadius` to 5. All of this can be done from within the storyboard or using code.

Comment: Thank you so much, been trying to figure this out for so long!